# Cannot access go server from commandline / adding web server logic to existing code

Tags: http, go

In my first iteration, I got the following to compile and work:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func routineHandle (query string, ch chan <- string) {
  ch <- query
  wg.Wait()
}

func ping () {
  ch := make(chan string)
  wg.Add(1)
  go routineHandle("testquery",ch)
  wg.Done()
  msg := <-ch
  fmt.Println("Channel Message",msg)
}

func main () {
  ping()
}
```

This successfully uses 1 channel to perform the `goroutine routineHandle`

Now, I want to add web server capabilities which perform the following:

- Listens on a port and accepts/returns requests
- Hooks into the routineHandle so we can utilize that goroutine as an Api Server Method

My code is on a linux box without a gui so I don't know how to test the web server capabilities.

My code looks like as follows:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
  "net/http"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func routineHandle (query string, ch chan <- string) {
  ch <- query
  wg.Wait()
}

func ping (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ch := make(chan string)
  wg.Add(1)
  go routineHandle("testquery",ch)
  wg.Done()
  msg := <-ch
  //fmt.Println("Channel Message",msg)
  w.Write([]byte msg)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/",ping)
  http.ListenAndServe(":1234",nil)
}
```

You'll notice a few additions with my second piece of code:

- I added the `net/http` package
- I added the `http listener` to the `main method`
- I added response writer and request parameters to the ping function
- I changed from `fmt.Println()` to `c.Write`

The end goal would be for typing in a query, and then using that query in the `routineHandle` goroutine

**Like I Said Though,** I don't know how to test this final implementation on an `ubuntu box without a gui`

One last thing to note. If you notice any issues **PLEASE** let me know. I wonder if running a goroutine inside a http server would cause an issue

Comment: No I don't think so running routines with http server cause any issues. I have done it created routines to save data into database by using go routine inside my handler. Well all you can do is you need not use go routines. Here you are just handling the request in one go

Comment: @ThunderCat so you're suggesting i put my routineHandle code inside the ping method?

Comment: @ThunderCat Can you provide a workable solution? Im trying to understand where you want things to go

Comment: @ThunderCat but i might need to run concurrent operations in the future? can you provide an example with concurrency and channels?

Comment: Right now you do have problem with concurrency because of global shared waitgroup. Just get rid of it, http server takes care of it for you (each request will run as separate goroutine).

Comment: @ThunderCat I dont have an example that requires it at the moment but i was informed to use concurrency. Id really appreciate it if you could show me a concurrency example wtih http server.

Comment: @ThunderCat Right that I understand. What I mean was running go routines inside the server go routine utiilizing channels

Comment: @ThunderCat Ok well I guess Im on the right track. How do I add a new go routine in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question uses the wait group incorrectly (wait and done should be swapped, the group should not be shared globally) and redundantly with the channel. Delete the use of the wait group to fix the code.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func routineHandle(query string, ch chan<- string) {
    ch <- query
}

func ping(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go routineHandle("testquery", ch)
    msg := <-ch
    w.Write([]byte(msg))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ping)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```